# How do I successfully draw a bitmap onto another bitmap?

Tags: graphics, dictionary, bitmap, draw

I've been trying to do some map stuff for a game I'm working with. I'm looking to display 9 map files (which I've already read and processed, and have a function which converts these map files into Bitmap objects).

Basically I have an array of bitmaps, and a large bitmap. Each small bitmap is 256x256, and the large one is 768x768, and I want to draw them at the correct offsets (so it all lines up, each bitmap is designed to next to its predecessor, until end of row, at which point a column is used to start the next 3, and so on).

What I'm doing at the minute:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            bmpList[i] = getMapFile(sb[i].ToString());
        }

        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
        {
            g.DrawImage(bmpList[0], 256, 0, 256, 256);
            g.DrawImage(bmpList[1], 512, 0, 256, 256);
            g.DrawImage(bmpList[2], 0, 256, 256, 256);
            g.DrawImage(bmpList[3], 256, 256, 256, 256);
            g.DrawImage(bmpList[4], 512, 256, 256, 256);
            g.DrawImage(bmpList[5], 0, 512, 256, 256);
            g.DrawImage(bmpList[6], 256, 512, 256, 256);
            g.DrawImage(bmpList[7], 512, 512, 256, 256);
            g.DrawImage(bmpList[8], 0, 0, 256, 256);
        }
```

The result is that bmp is just a blank image (when I convert it to an Image.Source, it displays nothing. To prove the rest of the code I've done this:

```
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
        rect.Height = 256;
        rect.Width = 512;
        rect.X = 0;
        rect.Y = 0;
        Objects.Colour color = new Objects.Colour();
        color = colourlist[0];
        Graphics.FromImage(bmp).FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(color.r, color.g, color.b)), rect);
```

And it draws a black rectangle as expected, of 256 height and 512 width. I've changed these numbers to fill the rectangle, too, so that isn't the problem.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? All help will be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that actually there is nothing wrong with the above code, and that I was passing a file path incorrectly to another function. My bad, thanks anyway!